# Evaluating $\sin\frac{\pi}{2}\sin\frac{\pi}{2^2}\sin\frac{\pi}{2^3}\cdots\sin\frac{\pi}{2^{11}}\cos \frac{\pi}{2^{12}}$

Tags: trigonometry, problem-solving

Evaluate :
$$\sin\frac{\pi}{2} \times \sin \frac{\pi}{2^2} \times \sin \frac{\pi}{2^3} \cdots \times \sin\frac{\pi}{2^{11}} \times \cos \frac{\pi}{2^{12}}$$
I tried to solve it by using double angle formula, by replacing $\sin\displaystyle\frac{\pi}2$ with   $2 \sin\displaystyle\frac{\pi}4 \cos\displaystyle\frac{\pi}4$ and similarly replacing $\sin\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2^2}$ with double angle formula. But I'm not getting anywhere from this, can you please suggest me how can I approach to this problem, especially that cosine term at last is making everything so weird.
The thing which is most important to ask is : although I know every theory which applies over here but then also why I'm unable to solve this question? What is the reason for my failure?

Comment: Let me suggest that to improve the readability of your question, you set your formulas in [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). I did part of it for you.

Comment: @Jan What about the $\cos{{\pi\over12}}$ at the end?

Comment: Also, the reason for failing at something is usually that you haven't yet found the path to success. You could give up (sometimes a realistic choice), or you could keep trying.

Comment: One way is to convert the product into a sum. Hopefully, a summable series (i.e., expressible in closed form) would result.

Comment: [Viete helpful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viète%27s_formula#Derivation) ?

Comment: @Allawonder I tried converting the product into sum by taking natural log of the expression but I’m not able to go after this.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thank you for giving Viete formula because I didn’t know of that formula. But I’m unable to use it to get the solution.

Comment: Try writing $\sin(x) = (e^{jx}-e^{-jx})/2j$. It might help simplify the expression a bit.

Comment: I wonder in what situation you met this problem. Did you find this problem in some book, or some other resources?

Comment: @DoyunNam This question came in my exam of IIT JEE Mains 2019.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever you would do, the result would be a very small number very close to $0$
$$\sin\frac{\pi}{2} \times \sin \frac{\pi}{2^2} \times \sin \frac{\pi}{2^3}\times \cdots \times \sin\frac{\pi}{2^{11}} \times \cos \frac{\pi}{2^{12}}$$

We know the value of the sine for some of the angles. The first are
$$\{1 , \frac {\sqrt 2} 2,\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}} }{2}  \}$$ and the pattern continue for ever.

For the next one, corresponding to $\sin \frac{\pi}{2^8}$ the exact value is
$$\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}}}}}{2}\approx0.012271538$$ while
$$\frac{\pi}{2^8} \approx 0.012271846$$ that is to say that you can *approximate* all the sines by the argument. Concerning the cosine, the argument is so small that you can assume it is almost equal to $1$.

If you take into account the fact that $\sin(x)<x$, an upper bound for the product of sines would be
$$ \frac{ \pi^9 \,\sqrt 2}{2^{64}}\approx 2.285 \times 10^{-15}$$ while it should be $\approx 2.208 \times 10^{-15}$.

Concerning
$$\cos \frac{\pi}{2^{12}}\approx 0.99999970586$$

All of that makes the value of the expression quite close to the machine epsilon.